# Поиск всех топологических сортировок

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Меня интересует, существует ли алгоритм для нахождения всех топологических сортировок в графе.

Comment: их может быть порядка N!. Не думаю что сильно быстрее лобового в худшем случае будет.

Answer (score 4):

Да, конечно. В "*Искусстве программирования*" Кнута, томе 4А, на стр. 395 есть алгоритм V - *Все топологические сортировки*.

И вообще, см. раздел 7.2.1.2, на стр. 393-396.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/102166)

Comment: @ИванПшеницын Это -  самый полный ответ на вопрос. Существует ли алгоритм? Да. Есть ссылка на вечное :), а не на сайт. Как вы себе представляете более полный ответ? Как просто набор этого алгоритма? Пару страниц с формулами? У меня не комментарий, а предельно полный ответ. Ваше замечание считаю пустой придиркой не по делу :)

Comment: @Harry лучше бы фрагмент статьи) мне вот интересно стало за его асимптотику пришлось гуглить.